# Why is the 'problem of evil' considered so difficult?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, ontological-argument, problem-of-evil

If one believes in the 'supernatural' and some Supreme Being affecting our lives in various ways; if you believe we have free will and free choice and this Being allows us to have and use this 'free choice' and do whatever we wish then we 'create' any evil, if some people do in fact do 'bad things'.

So why does evil exist if there is a benevolent Superior Being - because (if one believes in this Being and the possibility of free will) this Being allows us to have free will and create situations where we might initiate 'good' or 'bad' events relative to ourselves or others.

If one doesn't believe in the possibility of free will then we are just puppets and puppets can't do evil (except in horror movies). If one doesn't believe in a Superior Being then the 'problem of evil' does not exist ( and can not be used as an argument against the possibility of a Supreme Being).

So why is this 'problem of evil' used as evidence against the supernatural?  And why is this problem of evil considered so hard for western religious apologists to solve?

Comment: The 'problem of evil' only exists in western theology. What is thought of as evil in one place, time, and circumstance is not necessarily evil in another. There is no problem of evil in Eastern philosophy.

Comment: Creating two newlines after a paragraph should create a empty line between those paragraphs. Or, end a sentence with two spaces and a single newline should move the next sentence to the next line.

Comment: If a nutty scientist isolated on an island in his lab made a lot of different robots ,all self-sustaining and self controlling ; all able to 'set-up' their own goals and 'work towards' them ; all capable of reprogramming themselves ( without any disfunction) , the question arises what might these robots end up doing? Competing for resources or cooperating ; maybe they would behave a lot like people have done. The scientist might not have had any thought of any inevitable behavior . He might have wanted to make robots that could 'behave' for themselves with no strings attached.

Comment: Interesting that the core text in Judeo-Cristian thought begins with a story of Adam and Eve.  They were commanded to not eat from the "Tree of knowledge of good and evil."  Does than mean we are not to make judgements on what is good and evil?  After all, unless we have atleast an understanding of what is evil, how can we recognize it?

Comment: Adam and Eve were not supposed to eat from the Tree of Knowledge but they did doing a basic sin of disobedience. But this shows they had free will and were not robots even though they were influenced by evil suggestions that they did not have to follow. This of course is all if you believe in the Bible.

Comment: The problem of evil is why would a benevolent Supreme Being that created everything would allow evil to exist. Well this Being ,if you believe in this, created us with the ability to 'make' our own 'plans' about anything and carry them out. If this being stopped any 'evil' behavior many of the plans some people choose would have to be stopped. So to have a free 'hand' in our own development we are allowed to make our own mistakes even if with deadly consequences.

Comment: Did C.S Lewis consider the problem of evil a serious objection to faith until he changed his mind about it?

Answer (score 6):

I think why you're not seeing the problem is in what you're eliding with "superior Being". The (traditional) "problem of evil" only arises if we describe a being that is omniscient, omnipotent, and good. (See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/#RelConGod -- added due to Swami's comment)

Without omnipotence, this being would not necessarily be capable of effecting what it wants in the world -- thus making evil possible.

Without omniscience, this being cannot know whether it's actions will prevent evil or not.

Without being good (and probably infinitely good), this being has no motive to prevent all evil.

The traditional definition of God in Christian theology is omnipotent, omniscient, and perfectly good. What you are suggesting as an answer is usually called the "free will defense" or "free will theodicy". It states much as you do that the source of evil is in the wills of the creatures God has created as free.

But this does not get God completely off the hook. Given the three perfections, it seems at least conceivably possible that God could create a world where no evil occurs and this at the very least *seems* better than a world with evil, and there's plenty of corners of the world where free will doesn't seem to outweigh this good (holocausts, grotesque sex crimes, atrocities), and where such free will seems to be curtailable.

Or to put it another way, a God with perfect foreknowledge, power, and goodness creates free beings who then commit these atrocities. If you drop any of the three, this seems hypothetically possible. With all three, then free will seems kind of flimsy for precisely the reason that it's one thing if you back your car into a child accidentally and kill them and its another altogether to knowingly back your car into a child even though you didn't see them at that immediate moment. The challenge for classical theism is to explain how God creating is good when God creates with at a minimum full knowledge of the evil that will be in the world and the maximal set of powers and foresight to minimize evil.

Comment: A Neo-Platonist argues that evil is integral to creation and without it there could be no creation. Otherwise creation would be identical to God. You are either God and infinitely good or are among creation with varying degrees of good and evil.

Comment: @infatuated - I agree. The neo-Platonic is not perfectly powerful being equalled by a kind of negative force of equal power.

Comment: I am not sure which brand of Neo-Platonism you're referring to but Plotinus as the founder of this tradition holds that evil emanates from non-existence or deficit of existence, and since only "the One" is infinitely rich in existence He is infinitely good, other beings incarnate evil in proportion to their lack of existence. This is also the view held by muslim philosophers who expanded on the Neo-Platonist tradition.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to Manichean neo-Plationsim. But there are several groups of neo-Platonists who posit the active principle and chaos as equal and opposite -- with neither being infinite. I'm not sufficiently familiar with Islam to know for certain but I don't believe that feature was accepted by most Islamic philosophers (though I do believe some held heretical views on the nature of God vis-a-vis islamic theology)

Comment: How could an omnipotent Supreme Being with a maximal set of powers and foresight to minimize evil use these abilities without restricting what certain people involved in a potentially 'evil' situation can do? That is if someone is thinking of choosing various options leading to his actions of stealing something or hurting someone then for a Supreme Being to intervene means forcing the person not to make certain relevant choices and maybe restricting his actions by other possible means. Thus preventing the person in this case of using his free will.

Comment: Yes, That's the Manichean belief but not necessarily a feature of all Neo-Platonic traditions.

Comment: @201044 that comment makes little sense if you don't think there's a difficulty in the traditional problem of evil. But (1) it seems a God perfect in all three ought theoretically to be able to create a world where people freely choose what they do without them producing atrocities. (2) It's not clear the value of freedom is sufficient to outweigh the value of all the evils it brings. Thus, the problem with the free will defense (already mentioned in the body of my answer).

Comment: If you believe in what the King James Bible says , it says 'the human heart is evil beyond understanding and who can know it..', so this Supreme Being 'allows us to be existing and 'try' to 'figure out' our own senses of 'morality'. This Being doesn't allow evil but does allow us to try to figure out what is 'evil'. Many people are certainly capable of creating evil 'events'. Any type of supernatural intervention if one believes that is possible , would have to prevent the person from using free will.

Comment: @201044 it also God searches the hearts of men and knows their hearts. / You don't seem to be understanding (1) or (2). An omniscient God would know the evils that would take place (on a classical definition of omniscience) given a particular creation. And thus merely saying "free will" (which I repeat for the third time is one strategy to combat the problem of evil) does not eviscerate the problem's existence because God knows when God creates the problems that will arise in that world.

Comment: Or to put it another way, if you think God doesn't know the evil that will happen, then you are committing yourself to either a process view of God or open theism (which don't agree with the classical theological definition of omniscience).Doing so is one strategy to try to resolve the problem of evil. Not all theists are committed to that strategy.

Comment: If a Supreme Being ( and I'm not just talking about the Christian concept ,God) could create a world where people freely choose what they do based on their awareness of what they can do ,and in such a world nothing bad happens; the thing is what would be their awareness of what behavior is acceptable ? This Supreme Being can not prevent a person from becoming aware of the basic idea of stealing ,say. If the Being created a possible perfect world where people could use free will and never have problems the Being would have to restrict our awareness of possible ways of interacting.

Comment: First, as a I explained in the answer, "Supreme Being" is deeply ambiguous (the word God is the one we get from Aristotle -- a non-Christian who gives the definition and used by Christians, Jews, and Muslims -- the main groups that posit a supreme being [no such being is posited in most Eastern religions]). Does such a "supreme being" have omniscience, omnipotence, and perfect goodness?

Comment: Second, your thought experiment assumes stealing is a fundamental possible feature of reality. There's no reason to assume that. In a word without a concept of private property, stealing is impossible. You seem to be committing this God to wanting to create a world where people have unrestricted "awareness of possible ways of interacting". But why is this God committed to that?

Comment: Which has nothing to do with anything I claimed or with your original question nor demonstrates any understanding of anything I've written in my answer...

Comment: I had brought up the Neo-Platonic view as a fundamental solution to problem of evil but the discussion deviated to the doctrine of a specific tradition of Neo-Platonism (Manichean) which not what I had meant. And you never addressed the solution by Plotinus that I had mentioned. The idea was that "the One" (God) should either create (which would necessarily cause evil for creation is necessarily imperfect compared to the One) or never create in which case the One would have to withhold some of His perfections such as benevolence (or this would necessitate negation of some of His perfections).

Comment: So the One has to do what is a consequence of His perfections, that is to create. But evil is a necessary consequence of creating for any creation has to be imperfect or there would be a conflict of having two perfect beings which means having two Gods which is absurd for there can not exist two infinite Gods.

Comment: @infatuated Plotinus' solution denies the perfect goodness of God. Moreover, it's a type of process actualization view regarding knowledge (if memory serves). But that is *a solution*

Comment: For Plotinus the One is also the Good, and the source of all goodness. So I don't see how his theory denies the perfect goodness of God. And I not sure how the process actualization view relates to the problem.

Comment: because his concept of God is imperfect if it does not create -- thus differentiating it form Plato's God (where the demiurge creates) and Aristotle's and the classical theist account (where God is free to not create and still be perfect in every way).

Comment: @201044 this site isn't really a forum or meant for debate. It's premised on the idea that you have a question that is answerable in much the same way as a programming question.

Comment: @201044 consequently, I assumed that you were legitimately trying to understand why there is something in philosophy of religion called the problem of evil and that you wanted to understand why within the tradition of philosophy, it was ever considered a problem. Net outcome: you don't because you believe strongly that the free will theodicy resolves the problem (or you imagine religious believers do). Plus some weirder personal variants sprinkled in about whether evil is a proper object of learning. / This format can't really help you with that. Or at least I don't care enough to do so.

Comment: I would like to know why the problem of evil is such great evidence against ANY Supreme Being and no body has answered this ,they have only proclaimed and defended their own positions. @ virmaior ' thank you for admitting you don't care enough to help. That confirms what I was saying before.

Comment: @infatuated you are correct about Plotinus and Neo-Platoinism

Comment: @virmaior You state - "The (traditional) "problem of evil" only arises if we describe a being that is omniscient, omnipotent, and good." Unfortunately I do not see how you draw this conclusion. The problem of evil only arises if you assume there are two dueling Gods, one good and one evil. In that case neither is omniscient or omnipotent.

Comment: @virmaior; The One also "creates" but that takes place through *emanation.* Many Neo-Platonist Theists also explain the nature of the act of creation by God in terms of Plotinus's theory of emanation.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda heh? not at all sure what you're talking about. The traditional problem of evil arises in a monotheistic context (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_evil / see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/evil/#RelConGod stipulation #1)

Comment: @infatuated are muslims normally committed to an emanation view of God? (I've studied neo-Platonism, it's just been years and  I never associated it with Islam at the time).

Comment: @201044 again, I think you're confused here. I'm willing to answer SE-style questions. I would say in your case, the question is not as advertised because you should include all of the elements you want to hear in the question -- not in comments sprinkled throughout each person's response to your question. This is called "scope creep".

Comment: @201044 rereading your comment above: " would like to know why the problem of evil is such great evidence against ANY Supreme Being", I'm answering precisely that. I don't know what bible verses have to do with it. It's simple. **Make God perfectly good, perfectly knowing, and perfectly powerful. Why is there evil in the world?** / As I stated the freedom answer is one called the "free will theodicy". But it's not patently clear that freedom requires evil. My wife and I are both free but that doesn't mean either of us expects the other to have affairs.

Comment: @virmaior, A significant number of muslim sufis and scholastic philosophers yes, they were/are committed to synthesized brands of Neo-Platonism which involve emanationist understanding of Divine creation.

Answer (score 2):

Mystical spiritual minds and traditions would say that both good and evil are merely elements of the cosmic drama, and each has something to teach the evolving soul in its journey toward perfection. Western minds and traditions tend not to look so philosophically on life.

What leads us to refer to something as "evil" ? Because it causes shock and pain ? Isn't it a bit high and mighty for us to judge a cosmic deity as having created "evil" just because we don't like it ? It seems like the grown-up version of an outraged infant throwing a tantrum because they don't get ice cream for dinner. If you believe there is no afterlife, then life is over in a blink and what does it matter? If you believe that the virtuous go to heaven, then all's well that ends well and what does it matter. If you believe in reincarnation, then everything presumably will work itself out in the long long run.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the problem of evil as normally understood...

Comment: An alternative, then. Solution via transcendence.

Comment: @JonathanDunn You are correct. There is no problem of evil in the Eastern tradition. 'the problem of evil normally understood' is where 'normal' means only in an acceptable Western context.

Comment: The problem of evil does not prove ANY concept of a Supreme Being is false.

Comment: @virmaior This might not be the answer I would choose, but it seems perfectly on topic to me --I'm not sure why you see it as non-relevant.

Comment: @ChrisSunami among other things, my comment was pre-edit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem of evil is technically only "difficult" with reference to certain attributes which the God of classical theism has.

> So why is this 'problem of evil' used as evidence against the idea of
>   a superior Being?

Since you have mentioned evidence, I believe that the evidential problem of evil is what you are talking about, as opposed to logical problems.

Here is one such evidential argument:

**The Argument from the Flourishing and Languishing of Sentient Beings (AFL)**

> Only a fraction of living things, including the majority of sentient
>   beings, thrive. In other words, very few living things have an
>   adequate supply of food and water, are able to reproduce, avoid
>   predators, and remain healthy. An even smaller fraction of organisms
>   thrive for most of their lives, and almost no organisms thrive for all
>   of their lives. If naturalistic evolution is true, this is what we
>   would expect. If all living things are in competition for limited
>   resources, then the majority of those organisms will not survive long
>   enough to thrive. Moreover, even those organisms that do thrive for
>   much of their lives will, if they live long enough, deteriorate.
>   However, if theism is true, why would God create a world in which all
>   sentient beings savagely compete with one another for survival? Does
>   anyone really believe that this could be morally justified? The fact
>   that so few sentient beings ever flourish is more likely on naturalism
>   than on theism.

The above is an informal statement of the argument.

See :http://www.patheos.com/blogs/secularoutpost/2012/06/08/the-argument-from-the-flourishing-and-languishing-of-sentient-beings-afl/

for the logical form.

Comment: If theism is true, why would God create a world in which all sentient beings were able to do anything each of them wanted to do with NO restriction put on them by ANY 'outside' source? If this didn't happen and each sentient being had behavioral limitations put on them like strings from a puppeteer, so they wouldn't act with intense greed or competition they wouldn't really be 'self-controlling' sentient beings..

Answer (score 0):

I believe strongly that the belief that God allows evil to exist is a false dichotomy. Who is to say he does not partake in many actions to stop evil from being?

Who is to say that the pure chance event of the lady who saw the ticket in the car that led directly to David Berkowitz's arrest was not led there as result of a pure act of God?

Who is to say that God did not use the American military to exact his judgment on the wicked Nazis?

I think that at least in the revelation that the Christians hold this is not a deist styled creator that thinks it good to not intervene in the actions of his creations.

He uses his own people the Jews to exact his judgment on the wicked. He uses floods and all manner of other methods to stop those who he knows will only do bad.

I see no reason to think why a Bible adhering Christian would think that type of intervention that happened in Biblical times would not continue to modern times.

Comment: Your answer is prejudiced especially on the political examples. Not only it is based on the Allied narrative of WWII which pains US as the good side and the Axis as the evil side, but it also fails to appreciate the evil admitted by US even according to standards history: nuclear bombing of Japan! The theological arguments are also more rhetorical than reasonable.

Comment: The holocaust must have made them the goodies how unreasonable of me for not realising that.

Comment: The Holocaust story is part of the official Allied narrative of the WWII. They have also successfully managed to suppress any alternative view as "anti-American" "anti-Semitic" etc. But if you are daring enough to look beyond political mass conditioning then I'd recommend you to study the revisionists' side as well! You will be shocked by what you will discover as I've been!

Comment: But if one believes in an Omnipotent Superior Being  this Being 'allows' us to exist and exercise free will which means this Being does not restrict our actions, regarding many situations. So we can 'do' 'whatever' we want. So in a sense this Being ( if you believe in this , the supernatural) is 'allowing us to 'figure out' what is right or wrong , what helps or what hurts. Of course various such belief systems have special texts to 'give' wisdom and related info. to those who are concerned. So this Being doesn't 'allow' evil but does allow us to 'figure' out any 'morality' for ourselves.

Comment: But God isn't letting us "figure out" anything if he created us, he knows exactly how we will act, and on top of that he can see into the future to double-check his perfect creation skills. So God from the moment he designs each and every one of us, he knows what we will do, knows Hilter will kill millions. To suggest he does that to make the rest of us stronger, or the world otherwise better in some way, is sadistic to say the least. The argument is strong because there is no reasonable way someone could argue in an all-loving God with the power to stop evil, but chooses not too.

Comment: The Supreme Being (if existing) knows all the things we will think and do but we don't; we don't know in many cases know what we will do so we can 'do' any actions we want and from our own points of view and figure out our own views on our personal sense of morality. The Supreme Being if this Being exists allows us to ,with trial and error and/or hopeful wisdom to manipulate our own lives and personal 'moral behavior' even though the Being knows exactly what we are and will be doing. ( don't defend your arguments with statements meant to intimidate ,like 'is sadistic to say the least.')

Comment: @NeilMeyer This doesn't address the problem of why evil exists.

Comment: @Chris I disagree those who claim that the problem of evil is a problem for religious belief often claim that God allows evil to happen. A claim I try to contend in my answer.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - Yes, but the problem is why is there evil in the first place, if God is all-powerful?  Some people conceptualize God as fighting eternally with the devil, but that's a bit too Manichean for me.  I could see your answer as acting together with the free-will defense (or a different argument), but not by itself...

Comment: The question is not why evil exists. I have answered the question as best I could I'm done debating it now.

Comment: The so-called 'problem of evil' is used to discount the possibility of any benevolent Supreme Being existing by saying why would such a Being allow 'evil' to exist if this Being is somehow 'present' and capable of effecting our lives. So the question is not why evil exists but why we are existing in a 'partly' evil environment with many who are capable of 'evil activity' IF there is a Supreme benevolent Being..

Comment: About the comment ,'isn't letting us figure out anything if He created us He knows exactly how we will act..' Well people do learn things they don't know. People through trial and error learn how to handle things and other people. We do and are figuring things out. Of course a  Supreme Being knows what we are going to do before we do it but the point is we don't know what we are going to do 5 minutes say , before we do it. And we base are actions on what we are figuring out.

Comment: If one believes in a Supreme Being and the subsequent creation of the Universe and the Earth and human beings the thing is this Deity created the 'initial states' for humans and the Earth ; this Deity did not create Human history also , we create that and are creating that ourselves. (the only way this Deity could have 'created all of Human history all at once before the actual 'human history' got 'started' is if the idea of absolute fate or strict determinism was real and we are just puppets. We can't initiate any actions good or bad ourselves).

Answer (score 0):

Your question - "So why is this 'problem of evil' used as evidence against the idea of a superior Being?"

This problem of evil as evidence against a superior Being only arises in the western monotheistic traditions. It does not arise in the Eastern traditions. In an Eastern context, there is no good or evil, both are illusions. There is only God, the non-dualistic Brahman. Good and evil are illusions that can be seen only from a relative standpoint, not an absolute standpoint.

Good and evil are relative terms, there are no absolute good or evils. What is considered evil in one location at one time is not necessarily evil at another time or place. Example: Several hundred years ago it was a common accepted practice in Europe to put a deformed or crippled newborn outside the dwelling and put them "in the hands of God". Of course what happened was they froze to death, starved to death, or were eaten by wandering animals. This was not considered evil. Today such an action would be considered evil. Even today, what may be considered good in one culture is evil in another.

From the standpoint of the Godhead, all the worlds and their objects are reduced to an illusory appearance. Does the water in a mirage make the earth wet? Likewise, how can illusory evil affect the One Reality? How can illusory good affect the One Reality? (*Pancadasi* II. 97.)

There is no free will. Krishna says in the *Bhagavad Gita* (XVIII. 60-61.) "Bound by your own karma, O Son of Kunti, which is born of your very nature, what through delusion you seek not to do, you shall do even against your own nature. The Lord dwells in the hearts of all beings, O Arjuna, and by His maya causes them all to revolve as though mounted on a machine."

David Loy in his book *Nonduality: A Study in Comparative Philosophy* quotes William Blake's *Vision of the Last Judgment*:

> Men are admitted into Heaven not because they have curbed & govern'd their Passions or have No Passions, but becuase they have Cultivated their Understandings. The Treasures of Heaven are not Negations of Passion, but Realities of Intellect, from which All the Passions Emanate Uncurbed in their Eternal Glory.
>
> The Combats of Good & Evil is Eating of the Tree of Knowledge. The Combats of Truth & Error is Eating of the Tree of Life...Satan thinks that Sin is displeasing to God; he ought to know that Nothing is displeasing to God but Unbelief & Eating of the Tree of Knowledge of Good & Evil.
>
> I do not consider either the Just or the Wicked to be in a Supreme State, but to every one of them States of the Sleep which the Soul may fall into in its deadly dreams of Good & Evil when it leaves paradise following the serpent.

Comment: That's very interesting but I'm only thinking about why the western philosophers use this problem so much. I read C.S.Lewis used to use the problem of evil as evidence against the Christian God when he was an atheist but he later changed his mind..

Answer (score 0):

Intellectually, there are ways to address this problem (I'm personally much in line with the neo-Platonist line of thought described in some of the comments above), but it remains a living problem for any of us who have actual belief in an all-powerful God who is good and who loves us, because some of the atrocities that happen in the world are so horrible and so needless that they are difficult to reconcile with the experience of God.

There is also the problem for the free will defense of natural disasters --catastrophic things unrelated (typically) to human agency, such as storms and so forth.  For the neo-Platonist defense (defects in existence are necessary because otherwise creation would be perfect and thus identical with God) the problem switches to how a perfect being could be capable of creating something even slightly less than perfect.

For at least these reasons --and I say this as a person of faith --the problem of evil remains a significant one for anyone who takes faith seriously.

Answer (score -2):

Most religions, particularly Islam and Christianity, claim that God is ofcourse, omnipotent and is aware of the future. He has already decided your days in advance, and he has already decided how, when, where will you die. He has also decided ***everything you'll ever do***. From an Islamic/Christian point of view, you're asking this question because God decided for you to do so! He has a "supreme plan" for everybody, as it is finely stated in The Quran and The Bible, and this is where religion shot itself in the head without even thinking about it first. If God has a "plan for everybody" and if he has already "decided our days in advance", then aren't we some puppets fulfilling his plan? Let's suppose that Jack, on a rainy day, takes a walk around some garden for leisure and he sees some woman dressed in a black coat and now guess what, Jack is a notorious serial killer! Later on, he murders the woman and throws her body in a river nearby. Should Jack pay for his crimes? Ofcourse he should, you might say. But the truth is, that according to Islam and Christianity, Jack is sinless. It's God who wanted the woman dead and used Jack to get his plan done. After all, hasn't he already decided everything for everybody? If God has a "supreme plan" for everybody, then he must have had a "supreme plan" for Hitler. In this case, Hitler is absolutely innocent. God himself planned for all those people to die in the Holocaust, God just used Adolf to get his work done. If I ever murder somebody tomorrow, it's only because God decided for me to do so. When a woman orders the abortion of her child and lets her doctor do it, the woman and the doctor are absolutely innocent because God decided for that child to be aborted. God, in simple words, is responsible for every abortion in the world! (According to Islam and Christianity, ofcourse). Islam/Christianity claims that God has a plan for everybody, even every atheist in the world. God, according to them, is absolutely fine with people being atheist because he decided for them to be so. And this is why, my friend, the problem of evil is difficult. (and agonising to a religious scholar)

Comment: There are many different christianities (from a sociological point of view) and definitely not all of them would agree with this.

Comment: I'd agree with Keelan but go a step further: Christians who believe as the above claims are decidedly in the minority. This is one of the worst answers I've seen on PSE, because it claims that a particular school of thought believes _the exact opposite of what it actually believes_.

Comment: The problem of evil might be altered to say ; If a Supreme benevolent Being exists why would this Being allow any form of evil to exist, including us humans. If one believes in what the Bible says , the part where it says '..you who are evil know how to give good gifts to your children , how much better you're Father in Heaven knows how to give good gifts to you..'; in other words even though we are regarded as evil by Heavenly standards our Father is willing to give good gifts to us. So if one believes in the Bible we are 'evil' but the Lord wants to help us..

Comment: As I said the Bible ,(if one believes what it says) indicates 'we' are evil and obviously capable of evil actions. The Lord is 'perfectly good' and made us as we are yet The Lord is willing to help us not be evil. So this answers the problem of evil from the point of view of the Bible ( if one believes what the bible says might be true). A benevolent Supreme Being that 'caused' this reality and we humans to exist yet even though we are capable of evil actions this Being is willing to help us.